# How to write a SQL query which populate a column on conditional basis, from two of the existing column

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say there are three columns

```
TYPE    COUNT1  COUNT2
----------------------
A        20      -
B         -      33
B         -      41
A        32       -
B         -      45
```

So here we have values in COUNT1 only if TYPE = 'A', and Values in COUNT2 only for Type = 'B'

I want to write a query which can give me following output.

```
COUNT1/COUNT2   TYPE
--------------------
20              A
33              B
41              B
32              A
45              B
```

Answer (score 2):

Use coalesce function if column value is null:

```
select type,coalesce(A,B)
from tablename
```

Or use CASE WHEN if value is literal like '-'

```
select type, case when type='A' then count1 when type='B' then count2 end as value
from tablename
```

Comment: What is this "end as value" for?

Comment: value is the alias for column name